# array.map gives key prop error, despite passing a key prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to get rid of a warning. I have an array of data objects similar to the following:

```
    {
      table: 10,
      roundScores: [9, 2, 3, 4, null, null, null, null, null, null],
      isPlaying: true,
      total: 18,
      key: 10,
    },
```

I'm then using filter and map to output a list of Scoreline components based on the data in each object of the array:

```
  return tableScores
    .filter((score) => score.isPlaying || round === 1)
    .map((score) => (
      <Scoreline
        key={score.key}
        score={score.roundScores[round - 1]}
        table={score.table}
        round={round}
        total={score.total}
        setScore={setScore}
      />
    ));
```

I keep getting the following warning:

`Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.`

I thought passing the key prop would have taken care of this, but not the case.

I've tried removing the .filter call with no success.  I also tried storing the results of the map to a varialble and then returning it, but this also the case.

I've also tried wrapping the Scoreline component tag with a Fragment component and putting the key prop there, but that also doesn't work.

Here's the structure of tableScores:

```
    0: {table: 1, roundScores: Array(10), isPlaying: true, total: 29, key: 1}
    1: {table: 2, roundScores: Array(10), isPlaying: false, total: 0, key: 2}
    2: {table: 3, roundScores: Array(10), isPlaying: true, total: 18, key: 3}
    3: {table: 4, roundScores: Array(10), isPlaying: true, total: 18, key: 4}
    4: {table: 5, roundScores: Array(10), isPlaying: true, total: 18, key: 5}
    5: {table: 6, roundScores: Array(10), isPlaying: true, total: 18, key: 6}
    6: {table: 7, roundScores: Array(10), isPlaying: true, total: 18, key: 7}
    7: {table: 8, roundScores: Array(10), isPlaying: true, total: 18, key: 8}
    8: {table: 9, roundScores: Array(10), isPlaying: true, total: 18, key: 9}
    9: {table: 10, roundScores: Array(10), isPlaying: true, total: 18, key: 10}
```

Comment: Seems like `key` is not unique

Comment: Well you might have multiple of the same key... Please [edit] to add all the objects

Comment: At this moment I've hard-coded a key for each object in the list, so I don't think that's it.  I also reduced the list to one item to guarantee uniqueness, but still get the warning.

Comment: add the result of `console.log(tableScores)` to the question.

Comment: Maybe you have more than one list. And it's not that one which causes the issue

Comment: as @Konrad has pointed out, you are probably looking at the wrong list. The browser console will show all warnings that occur anywhere in your App. In the past I certainly was looking for issues somewhere in my code completely in the wrong component because I was confused which warning corresponds to which component.

Answer (score -1):

try `` key={`${score.key}${score.table}${score.total}`} ``, a combination of the values, to ensure its uniqueness.

Comment: That does not ensure uniqueness if the parts are not unique. As OP said, the field `key` is supposed to be unique and thus should be sufficient. Adding things does not help, it just obscures.

Comment: a key value with addition to the index may help

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).